# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: windows, mobile

Could any body solve my problem  i am developing windows mobile 6.1 app, when i execute the application  the following exception was thrown

Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

How can i solve this problem here i attached my code as below:

Public Sub New()
            Me._strConnection = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName.CodeBase()) + "\MRMClient.sdf"
        End Sub

## Region " Open Database Connection "

```
    Public Function Connect(ByVal _connection As String)
        _SQLConnection = New SqlCeConnection(_strConnection)
        If Not Connected Then
            _SQLConnection.Open()
            If _SQLConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                Connected = True
            Else
                Connected = False
            End If
        End If
        Return 0
    End Function
```

thanks and regards

brite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to connect SQL Server CE Edition to a SDF file and access it. To do so, you need to provide an appropriate connection string. You're just supplying a file name and that doesn't get the job done. You can find some sample connection strings, including one for connecting to an SDF file, at the [connection strings website](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-ce). Since your file path string isn't even close to the required connection string format, you get the error message you quote.